# Disable icon colorStateList in NavigationView

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library, android-navigationview

In my app today I have icons which doesn't just have a single color, but in some cases two colors depending on the data state in my app. This means I can't use the default tinting behavior in `NavigationView`.

It looks like with the new `NavigationView`, unless I specify a `ColorStateList` for my icons used in the list, a default `ColorStateList` will be made for me which uses my `colorPrimary` etc defined in my theme.

Is there no way for me to force NavigationView to stop tinting my icons?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

> Is there no way for me to force NavigationView to stop tinting my
>   icons?

There sure is. You can do so programmatically using [`NavigationView.setItemIconTintList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#setItemIconTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)).

And you can do so in your `XML` layout by using the [`NavigationView.itemIconTint`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#attr_android.support.design:itemIconTint) attribute.

**Programmatically**

```
yourNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

**From `XML`**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    ...
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/black" 
    ... />
```

**Results**

[image: results]

Comment: Setting it programmatically was the only way I could get it to work. Don't know why I didn't try that. I tried setting it to null in the xml but that didn't do anything. Anyway, thanks buddy!

Comment: You need to reference to a color when applying it in XML. For instance, `@android:color/black`. It has to do with the way the `ColorStateList` is initialized in `NavigationView`.

Comment: Yea, I saw that in the sources. But still didnt think of just doing it by code.. :)

Comment: Nice! I was annoyed with the same, but didn't try setting it to null in code. Thanks for bringing this to our attention. Much appreciated!

Comment: Is this applicable to colored icons? Or in vector images?

Comment: The proper way would be `app:itemIconTint="@null"` in XML, but `NavigationView`'s constructor checks for `hasValue` which eliminates that possibility. Setting `black` in XML is not the same, as setting `null` programmatically. If the icon is not transparent in the middle, it becomes a black blob.

Comment: What about setting app:itemIconTint="@android:color/transparent" ?

Comment: If you set @android:color/transparent it will make icon as invisible