# Navigation drawer item icon not showing original colour

Tags: java, android, xml, android-support-library

I'm trying to show an icon next to an item within my menu for my navigation drawer, but for some reason the icon always appears in grey rather than the original colour (brown). Is there any way of preventing this from happening in order to show the icon's original colour?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        if (navigationView != null) {
            setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
        }
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**drawer_view.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:title="Section">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_browncircle"
                android:title="Sub item 1" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

[image]

Comment: What's in your `ic_browncircle` ?

Comment: @YeLinAung A brown circle just like the icon above next to 'Sub item 1' but in the colour brown, not grey.

Comment: Maybe you can try `.setColorFilter(MY_BROWN_COLOR)` to that view ?

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 374, accepted):

I found the answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30632980/875249

To avoid the link its pretty straightforward:

```
    mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

This disables all state based tinting, but you can also specify your own list too.  It worked great for me!

Here is where you can get the details on creating a color state list, but its pretty simple too: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/primary" />
        <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </selector>
```

Comment: Yeah, I tested it on a Nexus 4 running API 17.  I also tested on the Android M preview.  ColorStateList has been around for a while and NavigationView is part of the support library so I don't see a reason why this wouldn't work all the way to ICS and possibly even further back.

Comment: Any XML alternative for this? Tried `app:itemIconTint="@null"` but no success.

Comment: Thanks, I was starting to get a headache with this issue

Comment: `mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);` This is the answer I was looking for so long...

Comment: Where do you use the selector?

Comment: thanks :) How would I go about having a tint set for all the icons but one. For one particular icon, i want the tint set to null (i.e.) one particular menu item icon appears in its full color in all states

Comment: Heyy @Chris is it possible to add image on right hand side of menu items

Answer (score 53):

Use

```
    mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

it's right. Also If all your icons in one color scheme (i had all white)
you can setup through xml file -         app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"

My case:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
    />
```

Comment: Do you know how to solve [this other problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811505/mapview-not-returning-to-normal-state-after-clicking-toggle-switch)

Comment: This one works well, `mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);` removes the default iconTint from all the icons . Now if you have your icon in red color, it would appear red, no iconTint would be applied .

Answer (score 5):

I've tried something similar in one of my app. And yes, it appears that the icon color doesn't change. But I've managed to do with another workaround. Here's my `ic_browncircle.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    android:tint="@color/brown"
    >
  <size
      android:height="3dp"
      android:width="3dp"
      />
  <solid android:color="@color/brown"/>
</shape>
```

Which I believe is something similar to you but it doesn't have any effect and doesn't change the color.

So what I did is this.

```
navigationView.getMenu()
    .findItem(R.id. navigation_item_1)
    .getIcon()
    .setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#b69260"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

And it seems working. Here's the result.

[image]

Comment: What about for pre-Lollipop?

Comment: I've been trying several solution for pre-Lollipop. So far, no luck yet :(

Answer (score 4):

If you create a project with navigation drawer which the `Android Studio` provided. In your Main Activity class, you can just simply add this line of code `navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);` to your `onCreate` method. Like this;

```
 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
 navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null); // <----- HERE
 setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using a tinted drawable, not sure if it works below 5.0.

Create a drawable and add the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_browncircle"
    android:tint="@color/brownColor"/>
```

And then change your menu item drawable to the one you just created. If that doesn't work, then I'm not sure of any other solutions. You can try this library: https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer I use it a lot in my projects.

Comment: This method doesn't work on API 17 (4.2).  The reason (at least in my experience), is that the navigation drawer automatically overlays a white icon with a black tint when you have your theme set to light.  When I remove the light from my theme my icons return to white like I intended them to be.

Answer (score 3):

Just add one line in xml

> `app:itemIconTint="@color/white"`

Comment: Or `app:itemIconTint="@null"`

Answer (score 1):

**Some how this code not working**
MainActivity.java

```
                NavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null); // not working
```

so  you can use it.

MainActivity.java

```
 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
   navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this); 
   navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null); // <-- HERE add this code for icon color
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

**1)** Go to the Design tab
**2)** Click on **navView**
**3)** Search *itemicontint* in properties
**4)** Write `null` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
 android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 BottomNavigationView navigationbtn = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);

 BottomNavigationMenuView mbottomNavigationMenuView =
                (BottomNavigationMenuView) navigationbtn.getChildAt(0);

       View view3 = mbottomNavigationMenuView.getChildAt(2);

       BottomNavigationItemView itemView3 = (BottomNavigationItemView) view3;

        itemView3.setIconTintList(null);
```