# Programmatically setting icon to navigation drawer menu item using drawable resource is always black in Android

Tags: android, android-drawable, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I am developing an Android app. In my app I am using navigation drawer and navigation view. I am setting menu items for them programmatically. I set drawable image resource as icon to them programmatically. But when I set icon to them, icons are always black event my image resource beautiful color image.

This is how I programmatically set icon to menu

```
Menu menu = leftDrawer.getMenu();
        SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu(MAIN_MENU_ITEM_GROUP_ID, 99, 99, "Others");

        subMenu.add(MAIN_MENU_ITEM_GROUP_ID,96,96,"Monthly Leaderboard").setIcon(R.drawable.leaderboard_icon).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LeaderboardActivity.class));
                return false;
            }
        });

        subMenu.add(MAIN_MENU_ITEM_GROUP_ID,96,96,"Settings").setIcon(R.drawable.settings_icon).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
                return false;
            }
        });
```

This is the screenshot of what I have got

[image]

As you can see icons are black.

This is one of my original icon

[image]

Why is that happening and how can I fix it to get colorful icon? I have to set it programmatically.

Comment: are you using DrawerLayout?

Comment: I found the answer from the given link.
[Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394265/navigation-drawer-item-icon-not-showing-original-colour)

Comment: [Similar code for your question. You can get reference from it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286822/how-to-force-use-of-overflow-menu-on-devices-with-menu-button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following line of code to resolve your problem...

```
yourNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null)
```

And,

If you want to give specific color then You can change the color by using `app:itemIconTint="@color/my_desired_colour" to NavigationView.`

The default tint is black.`

Comment: What if I want to set a specific drawable, not colour? What should I use? `app:itemBackground` doesn't seem to help. I want to use a gradient drawable.