# Navigation Drawer Icon Color

Tags: android, android-studio

My navigation drawer are showing icon in a filter not real color
how t remove this filter

i am new please help me step by step.

Thank you!

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Go to your Menu.xml file of the Navigation drawer and change the icons appropriately !!
Which might be at drawable folder or mipmap folder!!

Comment: i change it but change my color of icons and icons show up black !

Comment: The problem is the grey circles instead of your icons?

Comment: This problem may be duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/a/31999206/5183999

Comment: @nshmura i seen that but beacuse iam new bee cannot add to my code

Comment: @motis10 yes dude it change my icon color to gray so it seems like circle gray

Comment: Please add your menu.xml. In addition, why your icon of building is not tint in grey? Maybe the problem is in your icons? or the way you add it to the project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31999206/5183999). 
But I add answer for explanation.

Your layout file is like this:
(activity_main.xml)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    ...


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_item"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Your Activity is like this: (MainActivity.java)
Call `navigationView.setItemIconTintList`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...


        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

       ...
    }
    ...
}
```