# Having multi color icons in BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I have a BottomNavigationMenu and i want to use icons with 2 color.

But its forces me to choose a color for items, if i don't do that it is setting a default dark grey color instead  of my icon's actual colors.

How can i have a menu with multi color icons?

Picture Of Menu

[image: Picture Of Menu]

Picture Of My Actual Icons

[image: Picture Of My Actual Icons]

Code of BottomNavigationView

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/grey"


    app:menu="@menu/menu"
    >
```

Menu codes:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
        android:title="">
    </item>


    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_groups"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_group"
        android:title="">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_main"
        android:title="">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_explore"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_explore"
        android:title="">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_friends"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_friends"
        android:title="">
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: post your xml code snippet and menu item file code

Comment: @VishvaDave I've edited the post, you can check it.

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31999206/8089770 once

Comment: Yes, this does solve my problem. But this question title is going to be  useful for people who will search like me. I didn't searched as " original color" (: