# Icons brooken and see like they are grayed out

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I have a strange bug.

I have image as vector asset. It is created correct and see like:

[image]

I'm using it like menu icon on drawer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_about_us"
            android:title="@string/navigation_about" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

But in device it looked broken:

[image]

Do you see images on the background? It's vector assets too, but they works fine. I place it from code.

I have the similar problem with ViewPager icons. It seems like only icons are broken. So i have two vector assets:

[image]

[image]

I set this icons two different way(specially):

```
layout_tab.getTabAt(0)?.icon = activity?.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_type_bird)
layout_tab.getTabAt(1)?.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_hints)
```

And then i see:

One:

[image]

Two:

[image]

What is going on, why my assets broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assets are not broken, it is just that the navigation drawer automatically applies a color filter to the icons which makes them appear gray. It is similar for the tabbar (as it is trying to show the state)

The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394265/navigation-drawer-item-icon-not-showing-original-colour) shows how to stop this

Comment: Yes, you are right. `navigationView.itemIconTintList = null` and `layout_tab.tabIconTint = null` do the trick.