# Android - Why icon color is changing in default navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 1.4. I used default navigation drawer activity and changed default icons to mine.

[image]

As you can see icons have white area in the center. But when I run application on emulator, getting this result:

[image]

Why this is happening? How to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you have icons for all densities in your project?

Comment: Not yet. Is this important?

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621561/disable-icon-colorstatelist-in-navigationview/30632980#30632980

Comment: I thought it was an issue finding the icons, but turns out NavigationView tints the icons

Comment: As @AndreiVerdes suggested, NavigationView tints the icon. I have written this code: navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null); Now my icons are visible. Thank you, Andrei!