# Navigation drawer icon was not display in color

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I am new to this topic ,I am trying to display my icons in color ,I Import icon packages drawable import from default android studio 1.4 but unfortunatley my icon was not display in original color ,in my drawable folder images display in color ,but when i run that app images display in black and white color any one help me please how to get icon original color
[click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZHk4.png)

[here my icon color but displayedd in black and white color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDk6B.png)

Comment: I'm not here to decide how to design your app, but if you attach to the Material Design guidelines for the [Navigation Drawer](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-specs), the image is looking fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following line of code to resolve your problem...

```
yourNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null)
```

And,

If you want to give specific color then You can change the color by using `app:itemIconTint="@color/my_desired_colour"`
to NavigationView. The default tint is black.

Comment: i had different diffrent color for every icon@saurabh gupta

Comment: @Pavankumar..as defined in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621561/disable-icon-colorstatelist-in-navigationview ... try yourNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);..