# I want to change the icon in the navigation view

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-icons

```
<item
   android:id="@+id/nav_day"
   android:checkable="true"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_weekly_calendar"
   android:textColor="#ff00ff"
   android:title="Day Planner!" />
```

I want to know how to change the `color` of the icon of the menu item I get from the navigation view. I know that you can use `ItemIconTint` to change at once.
I want to use the original `color` of the icon as it is. What should I do?

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yourNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

You can check the duplicate question post here:
[Disable icon colorStateList in NavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621561/disable-icon-colorstatelist-in-navigationview/30632980#30632980)