# xml-Icons appear in white under with apilvl 24&25

Tags: android, vector-graphics

I have a strange one this time... I am using for the drawer Vector Drawables (for the first time). I set in my `build.gradle` that I would like to use the support-library for displaying my vectors. Depending on the api-level the icons now change their color. In the Android-Studio preview is everything fine and black like supposed to be.

I read the Tutorial at [developers.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio) and the Tutorial at [thefuntasty.com](https://blog.thefuntasty.com/android-design-quick-intro-to-vectordrawables-a7ad708d6f03). Both tips and tips did not help.

The first picture shows the Drawer with API-level 24 and the second one with API-level 27. Under API-level 23 the same has happend. My real phone (a Huawei P9 plus) with Android 7.0 displays the icons white.

[image: API-Level-24]

[image: API-Level-28]

The relevants `build.gradle` parts:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 26 // An internal room component does depend on it, so I must not change it.
        ...

        // User added
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    api 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    api 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'

    ... (Room & other components)
}
```

Also here the code for one of the vectors:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:autoMirrored="true"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M10,20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12,3 2,12h3v8z" />
</vector>
```

It is referenced in the drawer layout file:

```
<item
     android:id="@+id/nav_main"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
     android:title="@string/nav_bar_reverse_wherigos"
     android:tint="@color/text_color_primary" />
```

**EDIT:**
I have looked deeper in the problem. Now I can say that the value of `navigationView.getItemIconTintList().getDefaultColor()` is different on API 24 and 27. My question is solved when I have understood why this is the case, so that I can make the appropriate changed to my layout...

**EDIT 2:**
I can override the color on all API-levels with `app:itemIconTint="#000000"` or `navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);` but then the icon is always black and not blue when selected (like in the picture). Also I am interested really bad why the default is changing with the API-levels.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable icon colorStateList in NavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621561/disable-icon-colorstatelist-in-navigationview)

Comment: I will try this later. First I need some sleep but thanks for the thread. @Martin Zeitler

Comment: @MartinZeitler I now read the thread carefully which you linked and I want that the Icon is tinted by the Navigation Drawer but the not selected ones should not be white...

Comment: Okay, if I am using the approach from your suggested Thread the Icons aren't white anymore but I would love to have the behaviour from the second Screenshot....