# How to set these kind of colored icon in navigation view of drawer layout

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, navigationview, android-navigationview

Want to achieve colored icons in the navigation drawer as in the image below.

[image]

When I add icons in my navigation view menu automatically it becomes grey.How can I make the icons as its previous colored state like the below image.

Comment: what you want ? Your question is not clear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable icon colorStateList in NavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621561/disable-icon-colorstatelist-in-navigationview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621561/disable-icon-colorstatelist-in-navigationview/30632980#30632980) and this [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394265/navigation-drawer-item-icon-not-showing-original-colour)

Comment: When I add icons in my navigation view menu automatically it becomes grey.How can I make the icons as its previous colored state like the above image.

Comment: Check one of the links posted above, you'll find your answer. To avoid the link its pretty straightforward: `mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);`

Comment: Thank you guys fro your help..It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line after you have initialised `Drawer Layout` and `Navigation View`:

```
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

`navigationView` is your `Navigation View` Variable