# How to use images as icons in bottom navigation view [Android]

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add bottom navigation view like below:

[image]

But it is coming like below:

[image]

I tried all the options, but I don't seem to quite get through, everything I do is only changing the color but I am not able to quite achieve what I want to.

Code below

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        android:background="#232323"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/PrimaryText"
        app:itemIconTint="@null"/>
```

Navigation Menu :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_add_expense"
        android:icon="@drawable/addincome"
        android:title="Add Income" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_add_income"
        android:icon="@drawable/addexpense"
        android:title="Add Expense" />
</menu>
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: I have added the code, Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable icon colorStateList in NavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621561/disable-icon-colorstatelist-in-navigationview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set the Icon TintList to null programatically and you will be able to show your icons without any tint.

```
bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Comment: This is in the activity where the navigation view calls it right ??

Comment: Yes in the activity where you have put navigation view

Comment: Welcome . Upvote and mark answer correct for future programmers.